# In all tables which have a column with a given name, replace a character at a position based on the condition that it's not a certain letter

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have some set of tables where I need to find all column name containing string like `Test`. In these columns I have to check the actual value and if it does not have `D` in 4th character position. I need to update with `X` in the same 4th character position.

This query give me all the table and column list

```
SELECT      t.name AS 'TableName', c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%Test%' 
ORDER BY    TableName
```

Now for all the column list I need to write a query something like this which I am not able to figure out:

```
update table_name_from_above_Query
set one_such_column=Replace(oldvalue_withoutD_In4thPosition,oldvalue_withX_In4thPosition)
where one_such_column not like '___D%'
```

Finally I need to update value like these:

```
Column Old Value: ABCEFG
Column Update Value: ABCXFG
```

Comment: I need for you to give us some data example. Also I need to see some code you have tried yourself. Also I need to see your expected results.

Comment: @VBoka added some details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd first create a temporary table which holds all the tables found which match the column name ("Your query"). Then I'd use a cursor to go through all the tables in this temporary table one by one and run the update statement on them by executing a dynamic SQL query (building a string with the table names).

```
BEGIN TRAN

--Drop temp table if exists already 
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tablesWithColumn') Is Not Null)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #tablesWithColumn
END

--Create temporary table to store all the tables that have the matching col name
CREATE TABLE #tablesWithColumn
(
 tableName varchar(3000)
)

-- Check all the tables in the system that have the column name MYCOLUMNNAME
INSERT INTO #tablesWithColumn
SELECT     c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name = 'MYCOLUMNNAME'
ORDER BY    TableName
        ,ColumnName;


-- Create cursor for temp table that hold the current table in the list
DECLARE  @currentTable VARCHAR(3000), 


DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR
FOR 
SELECT tableName FROM #tablesWithColumn;

OPEN table_cursor ;

-- Read next row
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @currentTable;

-- Loop values, run the update statement with a dynamic SQL query and get the next table to process:

DECLARE @dynSQL as varchar(max)
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

-- Build the dynamic SQL string from the current table being iterated.
-- If the fourth chracter IS NOT a D, we use STUFF function to replace it.
    SELECT @dynSQL = '
UPDATE '+@currentTable+' 
SET MYCOLUMNNAME =
IIF( 
    SUBSTRING(MYCOLUMNNAME,4,1) <> ''D'', 
    STUFF(MYCOLUMNNAME, 4, 1, ''X''),
    MYCOLUMNNAME 
)'


   EXEC (@dynSQL )

    FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO 
       @currentTable
END;

--Close cursor
CLOSE cursor_product;

DEALLOCATE cursor_product;


 --Drop temp table 
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tablesWithColumn') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #tablesWithColumn
END


COMMIT
```

This will find ALL tables that have the column name specified and perform the replace on the column.  If you wish to match all columns that match '%MYCOLUMNNAME%', you will have rewrite above query so that the temp table stores the particular variation of the column name, set a variable for it for the cursor to fetch and then also update the dynamic sql to refelect that (SET '+@MYCOLUMNNAME'+...) instead of SET MYCOLUMNNAME.

Comment: This can be done without using a cursor, simply by generating dynamic update statements separated by `;` and run all of them at once.